# Scroll UIView to expand into iPhone X top notch

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, iphone-x

I have the following layout:

- `UIImageView`
- `UIView` (with `UILabel`)
- `UITableView`

As the `tableView` is scrolled up, the height of the imageView is decreased before actually scrolling the tableView. The following code is used for that:

```
let headerImageViewMaxHeight: CGFloat = 200
let headerImageViewMinHeight: CGFloat = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height

@IBOutlet var headerImageViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var headerImageView:                 UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var subtitleView:  UIView!
@IBOutlet var subtitleLabel: TextLabel!

private var contentOffsetDictionary: NSMutableDictionary!

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.isKind(of: UICollectionView.self) {

        let horizontalOffset: CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.x
        let collectionView: UICollectionView = scrollView as! UICollectionView
        contentOffsetDictionary.setValue(horizontalOffset, forKey: collectionView.tag.description)

    } else if scrollView == tableView {

        let y: CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let newHeaderImageViewHeight: CGFloat = headerImageViewHeightConstraint.constant - y

        if newHeaderImageViewHeight > headerImageViewMaxHeight {
            headerImageViewHeightConstraint.constant = headerImageViewMaxHeight

        } else if newHeaderImageViewHeight < headerImageViewMinHeight {
            headerImageViewHeightConstraint.constant = headerImageViewMinHeight

        } else {
            headerImageViewHeightConstraint.constant = newHeaderImageViewHeight
            scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0

        } 
    }
}
```

The following two images shown the current states of scrolled down or up:

[image: Scrolled down (initial state)]

**Scrolled down (initial state).**

[image: Scrolled up]

**Scrolled up.**

As you can see, initially the grey bar saying `To Table -> Table 1` is scrolled down and is about 60 high.
When it's scrolled up, it scrolles until the safeArea. What I want to achieve is that once it reaches the safe area, it continues scrolling up *into* the safeArea (top notch), while keeping the text in exactly the same place (topSpace to safeArea of the text should stay the same). So, basically growing the `UIView` to go into the safeArea.

[image: ViewController layout]
**This image shows the ViewController layout.**

- `Header View` can be ignored, as that is aligned to the top of the viewController, but no constraints to anything else than `superView`.
- `TopSpace` of the view in question, is 0 to the `UIImageView`.

Changing `headerImageViewMinHeight` to 0, makes it scroll up to the actual top of the screen, without expanding it. So this seems like a good start, but needs some extra logic or constraints.

As the `UIView` doesn't have a specific height constraint, changing its `UILabel`'s top space from `= 16` to `=> 16`, there's the warning of `missing Y constraint or height`.
Otherwise that, together with `UILabel`'s top space to the viewController's safeArea of `=> 8` sounds like it could work.

Any ideas are welcome.

EDIT: The following picture basically shows what I want, except that here the `UILabel`'s top is not aligned to the safe area.
What this picture shows is achieved by changing `headerImageViewMinHeight` to 0.

[image: Partial solution]

Comment: I think you need to uncheck `Safe Area Relative Margins`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's a good start. But that's not going to be the whole solution, as the `UILabel` still has spacing of 16 to top & bottom of the `UIView`, thus preventing the `UIView` to change its height.

Comment: Bit confused about `once it reaches the safe area, it continues scrolling up into the safeArea (top notch), while keeping the text in exactly the same place (topSpace to safeArea of the text should stay the same). So, basically growing the UIView to go into the safeArea.` So basically, you want to eliminate the space between the grey view (or text?) and the notch?

Comment: You're right, my explanation is not very clear. I added a picture at the bottom of the message. So, that plus having the top of the text still aligned to the safe area (thus the need to expand the UIView's height.

Answer (score 2):

Add constriant [image]

Uncheck constraint to margin [image]

double click on Align bottom/ Align top[image]

click on last baseline (for bottom)/ first baseline (for top constrraint)[image]

***DONE***